# Método map não funciona como o esperado

Tags: ruby

estou estudando Ruby (sem Rails, por enquanto).

E estou com o seguinte cenário:

agenda.rb

```
require 'set'

class Agenda

    def initialize
        @contatos = Set.new
    end

    def contatos
        @contatos.to_a
    end

    def query_by_email(email)
        contatos.flatten.select { |e| e.email == email }
    end

    def add(*contato)
        @contatos << contato
    end

end
```

contato.rb

```
class Contato

    attr_accessor :nome
    attr_accessor :numero
    attr_accessor :email

    def initialize(nome, numero, email)
        @nome = nome
        @numero = numero
        @email = email
    end

    def hash
        email.hash
    end

    def eql?(other)
        other.class == self.class && other.email == @email
    end

    def to_s
        "Nome: #{@nome}, Numero: #{@numero}, Email: #{@email}"
    end

end
```

e minha classe main.rb (que uso pra fazer testes..)

main.rb

```
require File.expand_path("contato")
require File.expand_path("agenda")

agenda = Agenda.new

a = Contato.new('Rafael', '98-88891948', 'faeldix18@gmail.com')
b = Contato.new('Rafael', '98-88891948', 'faeldix18@hotmail.com')
c = Contato.new('Renan', '98-88891948', 'renan@hotmail.com')
d = Contato.new('Renan', '98-88891948', 'igor@hotmail.com')
e = Contato.new('Renan', '98-88891948', 'frank@hotmail.com')

agenda.add a,b,c,d,e

puts agenda.contatos.map(&:email)
```

a última linha está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> > main.rb:14:in `map': undefined method`email' for # >> (NoMethodError)
> >      from main.rb:14:in `'

E percebi que se eu adicionar o método `flatten`, funciona como esperando.

```
puts agenda.contatos.flatten.map(&:email)
```

So não entendi o por quê, visto que o `flatten` não faz nada de especial, apenas retorna um array que já existia sem fazer nenhum tipo de modificação ou se quer mudar o tipo. Alguém poderia me explicar o por quê de ter funcionado?

(estou vindo do java, a única linguagem 'funcional' que já trabalho é o javascript)

Comment: Rafael pela resposta do @RohBarboza eu pensei em outra coisa, ao invés de usar `@contatos = Set.new` você tentou usar `@contatos = []`?

Answer (score 3):

Como mencionado por @Roh Barboza, o seu `#contatos` não está retornando uma simples lista de contatos. O problema real que precisa ser corrigido não está em como você executa o `#map`. O erro está aqui:

```
def add(*contato)
    @contatos << contato
end
```

Dentro dessa função, `contato` é uma lista de contatos e não um único. É a lista de argumentos passados para a função. Ela devia, em realidade, ser implementada assim:

```
def add(*contatos)
    contatos.each do |contato|
        @contatos << contato
    end
end
```

E pronto. Todo o resto está correto e vai funcionar devidamente.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente o seu **agenda.contatos** está retornando isso:

```
[
 [
  Nome: Rafael, Numero: 98-88891948, Email: faeldix18@gmail.com,
  Nome: Rafael, Numero: 98-88891948, Email: faeldix18@hotmail.com,
  Nome: Renan,  Numero: 98-88891948, Email: renan@hotmail.com,
  Nome: Renan,  Numero: 98-88891948, Email: igor@hotmail.com, 
  Nome: Renan,  Numero: 98-88891948, Email: frank@hotmail.com
 ]
]
```

Seu Array está dentro de outro Array, use isso:

```
agenda.contatos.flatten.map(&:email)
```

ou

```
agenda.contatos.first.map(&:email)
```

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do voto negativo, a resposta explica o por que o código funciona somente com o `flatten`, me parece a resposta correta. +1 para a resposta @RohBarboza

Comment: A necessidade de usar `flatten` nesse caso é um erro de design.